# How to add a column of data to existing data frames with a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I need to add a column of data to several data frames which represents a chromosome from which the data were derived. I've read many posts about adding a column to a data frame and they are all either too specific of answers or switch to using apply functions, which are quite opaque in how they operate. Can someone help me out here and show me the proper for loop and apply techniques, so I can start to unpack the apply + function(x) style?

I tried using paste0 to create a vector of objects to insert into the loop, but that fails. Here is the basic syntax of how I think the looping should works (but fails):

```
library(dplyr)

df.1 <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(100), V2=rnorm(100))
df.2 <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(100), V2=rnorm(100))
df.3 <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(100), V2=rnorm(100))

for(i in 1:3){
  df.i <- df.i %>% mutate(CHR = i)
}
```

This is the error I get with this code: Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'df.i' not found.

The output should look like this:

```
head(df.1)
          V1         v2 CHR
1 -1.3545128  0.8267013   1
2  0.3758215 -0.4475770   1
3  0.5209901 -1.1342161   1
4  0.7207743 -1.4273951   1
5 -0.3867220  0.2681198   1
6  1.3279556  0.6116999   1
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try putting the data in a list and loop over as follows.

```
df.1 <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(100), V2=rnorm(100))
df.2 <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(100), V2=rnorm(100))
df.3 <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(100), V2=rnorm(100))
df_list <- list(df.1,df.2, df.3)
for(i in 1:length(df_list)){
  df_list[[i]] <- df_list[[i]] %>% mutate(CHR = i)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the response, but the code doesn't add the column of 1's, 2,'s and 3's

Answer (score 0):

You can add column names:

```
column_names= ["Id", "Name", "Age", "Weight", 'mreading1', 'mreading2', 'mreading3', 'freading1', 'freading2', 'freading3']
df = pd.read_csv("defo.csv", names = column_names)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps me solve the problem. Can you clarify how this adds data to the data frames?

Comment: there is no need to use a loop it makes the task more difficult you can just create an object name as col=["columnnames"] then add your col to the dataframe individually like pd.read_csv("YourCSVFILE.csv",names=col)